# How and where to set company proxy in saucectl config.yml file in playwright

Tags: playwright, http-proxy, cucumberjs, saucelabs

I am not able to launch company url in Saucelabs from saucectl in playwright-cucumberjs framework.
Everytime it's showing access denied whenever the url is launching.
I guess I need to set the company proxy here but where in the config file I need to set it and how.

Here is my sample code for config.yml file-

```
apiVersion: v1alpha

kind: playwright-cucumberjs

sauce:

  region: us-west-1

  concurrency: 10
  tunnel:
    name: your_tunnel_name
    owner:tunnel_owner_username

  metadata:

    tags:

      - e2e

    build: "$BUILD_ID"

defaults:

  timeout: 5m

playwright:

  version: 1.35.1

rootDir: ./

suites:

  - name: My Cucumber Test

    # The browserName affects the browser metadata of the job as it shows up on the Sauce Labs UI. This value is made available as an environment variable `BROWSER_NAME` on the VM.

    # It's the user's responsibility to launch the correct browser using Playwright,

    # so that the Sauce Labs job metadata matches the actual browser used underneath.

    browserName: chromium

    options:

      paths:

        - "features/**/*.feature"

      require:

        - "features/support/*.js"

      format:

        - "json:my-cucumber.json"

npm:

  dependencies:

    # Following packages are required for running a playwright + cucumber test

    - "@cucumber/cucumber" # cucumber official suggested package

    - "@saucelabs/cucumber-reporter" # Sauce Labs report plugin. Generates a test cases report for display on the Sauce Labs UI.

    - "typescript" # typescript support

    - "ts-node" # typescript support

    # You can append your npm dependencies
```

Somewhere proxy has to be set here but where and how I don't know.
Please help me for this!

I tried adding HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY as stated in documentation but wherever I am declaring this it's showing error that it's not allowed here to declare.